# TSQL, case, convert, replace end

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string, replace, case

Need help understanding what I am doing with the syntax here, please help! I not only need to convert from float to decimal but I also need to override the original data being migrated to the same format and data (in this case) where necessary to match the newer data.

```
,CASE  
   WHEN fInvReqMargin IS NOT NULL THEN  
     (CONVERT(DECIMAL(7, 7), fInvReqMargin)(REPLACE(fInvReqMargin, fInvReqMargin, INVESTOR_REQUIRED_MARGIN_FC)))
   ELSE NULL 
 END as INVESTOR_REQUIRED_MARGIN_FC
```

> error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Thank you!

Comment: sheesh, that's quite a messy case statement. given its all using the one field, have you considered putting it in a scalar UDF? that way you can build up the value gradually.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense what you're wanting to do when `fInvReqMargin` is not null - are you trying to convert the replaced value into a Decimal, or add the converted value to the replaced one (but the parameters are incorrect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the CONVERT and REPLACE syntax.  Without seeing the data I can't determine if you're trying to supply the style parameter to [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  If you are then the syntax should be

```
CONVERT( DECIMAL ( 7,7 ), fInvReqMargin,(REPLACE(fInvReqMargin, fInvReqMargin, INVESTOR_REQUIRED_MARGIN_FC)))
```